# fila y columna de un tablero [python]

Tags: python, bucle-for

Buenas necesito que a partir de la posición de una celda me devuelva la fila y columna a la que pertenece, tiene que ser una tontería lo que me falta o lo estoy planteando fatal, pero no me funciona con el borde derecho porque sale del 
bucle antes de sumar pero si sumo manual falla en los demás.

[image: hon]

```
tablero =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]



#quiero la fila y la columna de la pieza 8

def fila_columna():
    fila = 4
    columna = 4
    inicio = 1
    posicion = tablero[7]

    for fila_pos in range (fila):
        for columna_pos in range(columna):
            if columna_pos == 3:
                columna_pos = 0
            if inicio == posicion:
                break
            inicio +=1
        if inicio == posicion:
            break
    return (fila_pos,columna_pos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Como de antemano sabemos que el tamaño del tablero es `4x4`, podemos usar el operador `%` o `remainder` para hacer el salto de fila, esto pasa cuando `i%4 == 0`, al hacer el salto de fila se sumaría 1 a una variable que cuente el número de filas, en ese mismo instante en que se hace el salto de fila, otra variable que lleve el número de columnas recorridas debe volver a ser cero, dado que es una nueva columna y cuando la variable `i` sea igual al valor que estás buscando en el tablero, esto es `ì == value` la función debe retornarte tanto el valor del contador de filas como el contador de columnas que tenga hasta ese momento, lo que sería algo más o menos así:

```
tablero =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

def fila_columna(value):

    count_fila = 0
    count_columna = 0

    for i in tablero:
        if (i!=value):
            count_columna += 1
            if(i%4 == 0):
                count_fila += 1
                count_columna = 0
        else:
            return [count_fila, count_columna]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(fila_columna(8))
```

En este caso yo usé `i!=value` como condición del `if` en lugar de `ì==value` para que mi función me recorra todo el tablero hasta que se encuentre con `ì==value` en el `else` y me retorne una lista con los valores de los dos contadores, si puedes observar el primer `if` podrás ver que se le suma 1 al contador de columnas cada vez que recorre un elemento del tablero, hasta que se cumple la condición del segundo `if` que nos hace el salto de fila, donde se le suma 1 al contador de filas y se "resetea" el contador de columnas.